# How should I add an onBlockActivated event that activates my Tile Entity in my MC Mod? (Forge for MC 1.11.2

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm having trouble adding an "onBlockActivated" event for the block in my MC mod that has a tile entity. The event should allow you to either store a specific item inside the block or take it from the block. I have the rest of the code set up, but this one part is getting me. I have watched many tutorials on this, but they're all outdated. Here's the code:

```
//tile entity code
package com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.tileentity;

import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.init.ModItems;

import net.minecraft.entity.item.EntityItem;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.nbt.NBTTagCompound;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;

public class TE_MusicPlayer extends TileEntity {
    private int musicDiscs = 0;
    //private String discName = "";

    //adds a disc
    public boolean addDisc() {
        if (musicDiscs < 1) {
            musicDiscs++;
            System.out.println("Discs: " + musicDiscs);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //removes a disc
    public void removeDisc() {
        if (musicDiscs > 0) {
            worldObj.spawnEntityInWorld(new EntityItem(worldObj, pos.getX() + 0.5, pos.getY() + 1.0, pos.getZ() + 0.5, new ItemStack(ModItems.exampleitem)));
            musicDiscs--;
        }
    }

    //writes to memory
    @Override
    public NBTTagCompound writeToNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.writeToNBT(compound);
        compound.setInteger("musicDiscs", this.musicDiscs);

        return compound;
    }

    //reads from memory
    @Override
    public void readFromNBT(NBTTagCompound compound) {
        super.readFromNBT(compound);
        this.musicDiscs = compound.getInteger("musicDiscs");
    }
}

//block code
package com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.blocks;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.MusicCrafter;
import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.Reference;
import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.init.ModBlocks;
import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.init.ModItems;
import com.cayoayt.musiccrafter.tileentity.TE_MusicPlayer;

import net.minecraft.block.Block;
import net.minecraft.block.BlockHorizontal;
import net.minecraft.block.ITileEntityProvider;
import net.minecraft.block.material.MapColor;
import net.minecraft.block.material.Material;
import net.minecraft.block.state.BlockStateContainer;
import net.minecraft.block.state.IBlockState;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityLivingBase;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.item.Item;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.tileentity.TileEntity;
import net.minecraft.util.BlockRenderLayer;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumFacing;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumHand;
import net.minecraft.util.math.AxisAlignedBB;
import net.minecraft.util.math.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.world.IBlockAccess;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class music_player extends BlockHorizontal implements ITileEntityProvider {
    public static final AxisAlignedBB COLLISION_BOX = new AxisAlignedBB(4 * 0.0625, 0, 3 * 0.0625, 12 * 0.0625, 4 * 0.0625, 13 * 0.0625);
    public static final AxisAlignedBB BOUNDING_BOX = new AxisAlignedBB(3 * 0.0625, 0, 2 * 0.0625, 13 * 0.0625, 5 * 0.0625, 14 * 0.0625);

    public music_player() {
        //material
        super(Material.GROUND);

        //names
        setRegistryName(Reference.MusicCrafterBlocks.MUSICPLAYER.getRegistryName());
        setUnlocalizedName(Reference.MusicCrafterBlocks.MUSICPLAYER.getUnlocalizedName());

        //creative tab
        setCreativeTab(MusicCrafter.CREATIVE_TAB);

        //default state
        setDefaultState(this.blockState.getBaseState().withProperty(FACING, EnumFacing.NORTH));
    }

    //item dropped
    public Item getItemDropped() {
        return Item.getItemFromBlock(ModBlocks.music_player);
    }

    //color on map
    public MapColor getMapColor() {
        return MapColor.BLACK;
    }

    //determines if full cube or not
    @Override
    public boolean isFullCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    //defines if opaque
    @Override
    public boolean isOpaqueCube(IBlockState state) {
        return false;
    }

    //defines that block is cutout of whole block
    @Override
    public BlockRenderLayer getBlockLayer() {
        return BlockRenderLayer.CUTOUT;
    }

    //outline of box
    @Override
    public AxisAlignedBB getBoundingBox(IBlockState state, IBlockAccess source, BlockPos pos) {
        return BOUNDING_BOX;
    }

    //collision detection
    @Override
    public void addCollisionBoxToList(IBlockState state, World worldIn, BlockPos pos, AxisAlignedBB entityBox, List<AxisAlignedBB> collidingBoxes, Entity entityIn) {
        super.addCollisionBoxToList(pos, entityBox, collidingBoxes, COLLISION_BOX);
    }

    //sets direction
    @Override
    public IBlockState onBlockPlaced(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, EnumFacing facing, float hitX, float hitY, float hitZ, int meta, EntityLivingBase placer) {
        IBlockState state = super.onBlockPlaced(worldIn, pos, facing, hitX, hitY, hitZ, meta, placer);
        return state.withProperty(FACING, placer.getHorizontalFacing());
    }

    //meta from state
    @Override
    public int getMetaFromState(IBlockState state) {
        return state.getValue(FACING).getHorizontalIndex();
    }

    //state from meta
    @Override
    public IBlockState getStateFromMeta(int meta) {
        return getDefaultState().withProperty(FACING, EnumFacing.getHorizontal(meta));
    }

    //creating block state
    @Override
    protected BlockStateContainer createBlockState() {
        return new BlockStateContainer(this, FACING);
    }

    //AREA OF FOCUS
    @Override                                                                                                       
    public boolean onBlockActivated(World worldIn, BlockPos pos, IBlockState state, EntityPlayer playerIn, EnumHand hand, EnumFacing heldItem, float side, float hitX, float hitY) {
        //CODE HERE
    }
    //END OF AREA OF FOCUS

    //makes container
    @Override
    public TileEntity createNewTileEntity(World worldIn, int meta) {
        return new TE_MusicPlayer();
    }
}
```

Please paste the code I would need in the answers section and explain it.
That would help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the TileEntity from the World, cast it to TE_MusicPlayer, then call the methods on that object.

```
TileEntity tile = worldIn.getTileEntity(pos);
if(tile instanceof TE_MusicPlayer)
{
    TE_MusicPlayer musicplayer = (TE_MusicPlayer)tile;
    //musicplayer.add/removeDisk logic here
}
```

Standard java practice is to start class names with capitals and use CamelCase (i.e. MusicPlayer instead of music_player).